# Linear Model for Longitudinal data: Should time be a categorical or a continuous variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I was reading through the two level longitudinal data section of "Broadening your Statistical Horizons" (https://bookdown.org/roback/bookdown-bysh/ch-lon.html#missing)

The example that they were going through uses a linear mixed model to investigate the longitudinal relationship between math scores at charter and public schools over a 3 year period. In this example, they treat time as a continuous variable (values ranging from 0 to 2 representing years from 2008). What are the implications of treating it as an integer rather than as a factor? In general, when should time be treated as a categorical/continuous variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with time as a regressor in models, the distinction between "categorical" vs "continuous" is, in reality, too vague to be meaningful except that "categorizing" (with dummy encoding) is generally the wrong way to go.

What most novice analysts mean when they say they adjust "continuously" for time is that they include just the linear term. So between day 1 and day 2, the same difference in response is expected (conditional on all other covariates) as is expected at day 10 and 11. Now, this isn't usually the case, but also for inference we might not care so much whether the fitted response is overly precise. It may suffice to select a linear adjustment for time when the objective is to model the first order trend of the response, e.g. the idea that forced expiratory volume (FEV) or the left ventricular mass (LVmass)is generally expected to increase with age over the duration of follow-up in this sample.

The truth is for the two examples (FEV and LVmass) the linear time adjustment has led to some known problems with diminished precision, such that even in large cohort studies, it was necessary to make higher, more flexible adjustments to achieve a desired level of precision. In these cases splines were used.

Flexible predictive models offer a highly precise and efficient go-between for linear adjustment and dummy encoding. Splines with appropriate choice of knots and polynomial representation can provide a highly precise (local) approximation of sophisticated trends including highly non-linear effects. Splines can provide predictions that are arbitrarily close to categorical encoding, but they do require the same preliminary specifications from the front-end user: i.e. you need to know the polynomial degree of the local trend curve, and you also need to prespecify the location of the knot break points.

To summarize: never categorize a continuous variable. Use a flexible predictive smoother, like splines, when the scientific question demands flexible adjustment for the a highly non-linear trend.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with AdamO in general, if time is inconsistently measured or you believe there might be a measurement error, then categorization might be entirely appropriate.  For example, suppose a measure is supposed to be collected initially and at 4 time points on the hour 1,2,3,4 where t0 represents the initial time point, t1 at hour 1 and so on.  If these are carried out over many different entities but the time measures are not uniformly taken, such that for some measures they took place at say 50m, others 55m, others 1hr 5m and so on, with only the time measures of 1,2,3,4 being known (ie no actual times are recorded, but they are all assumed to take place at 1hr, 2hr, etc) there is measurement error.  The assumptions that time does in fact take place at these 1 hr intervals and each measure correct is not accurate.  This doesn't imply the ordinal information is lost, but simply the exact times are unknown.  In this case, exploring things like quadratic or other non-linear time trends is inappropriate.  A more conservative approach is to use categorization to preserve the ordinal nature of the data, but to accurately reflect the lack of specificity with respect to time.  The results are at least robust to the measurement issue, but maybe not be as powerful as you would like as non-linear time trends cannot be explored or ruled out.